# Word usage for "excretion"!

Tags: word-choice

The feeling when a person wants to puke, is termed "nauseous". What if a person wants to excrete? What is that feeling called?

Comment: Some people hold that *nauseous* is something that causes *nausea*, after which point one is *nauseated*.  Under that system, a *nauseous* person is a *nauseating* person rather than a *nauseated* one.  See the difference?  Doesn’t matter: most people know no better and care less.

Comment: It depends on what sort of thing is being excreted. If it’s a phlegmatic discharge, then we could call them *sneeze*, and if it’s a lachrymose discharge, *weepy*. However, it doesn’t quite work to call someone who needs to take a leak *pissy*, as that means something else, and *drippy* sounds like a plumbing problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about a single word but how about "the urge to go"?

Comment: There is no single word, informal or medically technical for this. The term is 'feeling the need to defecate/urinate'. 'Urgency' or 'incontinence' are slightly different things. 'Tenesmus' is the feeling of not having done enough after having excreted. Informally, you say of yourself. 'I gotta go', and then your parents say 'number 1 or number 2', which tells them if they can just have you go by the side of the road or if they have to get off at the next exit. I found this by googling 'feeling the need to urinate'.

Comment: @Mitch Wrong. An informal term for 'urgently needing to urinate' is _bursting_. (I think 3 out of the first 10 of 3.7 million Google hits for 'I was bursting' fit.)

Comment: From the movie [Rat Race (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0250687/quotes) [Kimberly needs to go to the bathroom] *"Dad, I'm **prairie dogging it**!", "What the hell does that mean?", "You know, like when a prairie dog sticks his head in and out of the ground.", "Oh.", [Five seconds later] "Ugh!", "Ohh, god, I do **not** wanna picture that!".*

Comment: Ouch @FumbleFingers, neither did I. :)

Comment: @terdon: I thought I recalled Meg saying it in a Family Guy episode too, but I can't find any references to that one, so maybe I just got it confused with the movie. Anyway, if you trust [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=PRAIRIE%20DOGGING), their definitions are mostly consistent.

Comment: The need or urge to go is the most common terms. When you don't fell the need the need you can complain of not feeling the stimulus, or of not having any pre-warning, i.e incontinence.

Comment: *Dioretix, matter over mind*  Anyone? Anyone? // @Mitch, how about "The urge to purge"?  // FF, see also "turtling", same idea.

Comment: @tchrist neither *weepy* nor *sneezy* (which I assume you mean, not *sneeze*) mean "feels the need to" - at least not in the sense OP wants.  (*Dispositionally*, OK, but not *situationally*). // Re your first comment, 'citation needed'.  Even if "some people" hold that, the more common understanding is that someone who says "I feel nauseous" or "I am nauseous" feels *queasy* or *sick to his stomach*.

Comment: @Edwin: 'bursting' is for the very particular case of an immediate need, like the more formal term 'urgency', as in "I gotta go _now_". There ia no term that covers the general case of 'needing to go'

Answer (score 1):

There is no such word in English (compare to the Swedish suffix "-nödig" which means "needy" and can be attached to nouns and verbs such as "wee" or "poop" or "vomit".)